# group membership of www-data differs when script is run via php-fpm

Tags: php, bash, shell, sh

I have a strange problem here. I have a bash script invoked via php and somehow the group membership differs when invoked by php-fpm. When invoked from command line, www-data is member of the group `ums` but invoked by php-fpm it is not.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "$(id) \n$(id www-data)" > id.log
```

When invoked from command line everything is okay:

```
$ su www-data -c id_log.sh && cat id.log

uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),1055(ums)
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),1055(ums)
```

Same groups: id without arguments gives the same result as id with `www-data` as argument. But when invoked via php-fpm and nginx it behaves unexpectedly and www-data is not in the ums group:

```
<?php
exec("id_test.sh")
?>


$ cat id.log

uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),1055(ums)
```

When invoked via php from command line it’s different:

```
$ php -f call_id_log.php && cat id.log

uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),1055(ums) 
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),1055(ums)
```

php itself behaves as expected but php-fpm seems to create its own environment – does anybody have a clue here for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. After changing the group memberships of `www-data` php-fpm does not recognize that change before it was restarted. I did not expect that.

```
$ usermod -aG ums www-data
$ systemctl reload php5-fpm.service
```

And everything’s fine.